# Bug in Magento Curl.php

Tags: magento-1.9, bug, magento-connect-manager, downloader, curl

Is it a bug in `Magento 1.9.3.2` ?

I found this function in `downloader\lib\Mage\HTTP\Client\Curl.php`

```
/**
 * Set curl options array directly
 * @param array $array
 */
protected function curlOptions($array)
{
    curl_setopt_array($this->_ch, $arr);
}
```

Guessing `$arr` is `undefined` and should be `$array`

Answer (score 2):

**It's not really a bug, I'd say it's a human mistake** because fortunately for us, this `curlOptions` method is never used in the Magento core.

However, you'll face issues if you have extensions using it but as it sits in the `downloader` folder it should not be used externally as the right class to use is the `Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl` class.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at class history it seems to be a quite old bug you found there. https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
You can contact Magento support to report the bug.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will report this to the magento support team

Comment: At least it is correct in Magento 2: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/1507bb11a0d33a7fdd93e7b482d210f08dfb71a8/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php#L480 but as this bug does not have any effect, I don't think it will ever be fixed in 1.x